# wildfly сервер падает после запроса к браузеру

Tags: java, wildfly

Работаю в Intellej Idea, деплою на сервер war'ник (пробовал и с wildfly 11 и 12), после запуска происходит первый запрос к браузеру (устанавливается в настойках конфигурации запуска) и сервак падает с ошибкой -

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000173: An invalid control character [1093] was present in the cookie value or attribute
```

которая циклично повторяется пока не потушу сервер

Пробовал чистить куки у всех браузеров. Как то раз получилось запуститься после того как в настройках изменил браузер по умолчанию из хрома на оперу и заработало но только на 12 версии , 11 так же упала на старте. Потом перенастраивал на сервере datas source вроде больше ничего не трогал и все теперь получаю ошибку на любом сервере и с любым браузером по умолчанию.

Comment: А точно ли в war-нике все верно? Чистый wildfly стартует без проблем страницу по умолчанию открывает?

Comment: сам по себе сервак стартует без проблем, дело в том что мне сбрасывали рабочий варник и тоже при запуске проблемы были, короче говоря ответа я не нашел переустановил систему и все полетело с первого раза без проблем

Answer (score 0):

решения не нашел, была переустановлена система с 7 на 10 и все  заработало.

Answer (score 0):

В моём случае проблема была с именем компьютера - оно содержало русские символы и использовалось undertow в cookie. После переименования компьютера с использованием только английских символов всё заработало!